# How to choose the first "n" elements in R

Tags: r

(USING R)
So I imported a data set by using

```
xcars <- read.csv(file.choose())
```

and then I chose my data set which was originally an excel file.
So, I have a column named dist (short for displacement) and I want to choose the first 25 entries underneath that column and then plot it on a histogram, so I attempted the following.

```
carsUpTo25 <- xcars(1:25,)
hist(carsUpTo25$dist)
```

Of course this didn't work. However, any help on how I would do this would be helpful.

Comment: Please read this short intro to  ["Difference between brackets"](https://rpubs.com/dgolicher/2271).

Comment: `carsUpTo25 <- head(xcars$dist, 25)` will do.

Comment: There are lots of great resources for beginners in the [R Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info). I'd suggest looking at *An Introduction to R* for basics like how to index data frames.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
 hist(xcars[,dist[1:10]])
```